# Creating a database changelog xml file from an existing database (including stored procs) using Liquibase

Tags: java, xml, database, version-control, liquibase

Is it possible to create an initial database changelog xml file from the existing state of the database?

I believe I've generated the schema using generateChangeLog, but it doesn't seem to return the stored procedures (or the data).

I'm using SQL Sever 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the data using a diffTypes flag that includes "DATA". See http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html.

Liquibase cannot currently output stored procedures, however. For that you will need to use a different tool and include them in the generated changelog using the  tag.

Comment: Is there a tool to generate the changelog of procedures, functions and trigger ?

Answer (score 2):

download liquibase.jar , database driver and save to one directory (Ex:/home/mySystem/liquibase), in the command line change the directory to (/home/mySystem/liquibase) and run the below mentioned command

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=postgresql-42.1.3.jar --changeLogFile=db.changelog.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<databasename>" --username=<username> --password=<password> update
```

Reference link:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html

Answer (score 0):

I just yesterday discovered SQL Power Architect, which seems to be able to generate Liquibase configurations:
http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect

For more info on this combination see this blog post:
http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2010/11/data-modeling-part2/

Comment: Seems like sql power architect suffers from the same limitations when it comes to exporting procedures etc. "However, be aware that if you intend to copy more sophisticated concepts like check constraints, non-standard indices (e.g. Oracle’s Bitmap indexes), triggers, views or stored procedures as well, that Power Architect is not yet able to reverse engineer them automatically. You have to extract this information manually from your existing database and enter the concepts as special “Custom SQL” statements to LiquiBase separately."